# How to get value from list in java

Tags: java, list

I have a List with array of object values. I have to display value from the list of object.

```
  List InvoiceList =[{companyname=greytip1, invoiceno=GO/12/04/001,
  billperiod=Apr 2012, invoicedate=2012-04-18 00:00:00.0,
  servicecharge=2000.00, tax=399.00, netamount=2394.00, duedate=null,
  mailed=false, isinelekka=false, amountpaid=null, filename=Invoice For
  Apr 2012-1333340688550.pdf, cid=15, ismanual=true},
  companyname=greytip3, invoiceno=GO/12/04/002, billperiod=Apr 2012,
  invoicedate=2012-04-05 00:00:00.0, servicecharge=5000.00, tax=500.00,
  netamount=5498.00, duedate=null, mailed=false, isinelekka=false,
  amountpaid=null, filename=Invoice For Apr 2012-1333340842337.pdf,
  cid=16, ismanual=true}]
```

from this InvoiceList, I need to get netamount from each object and add it.

How to do it in java?

Comment: Please clean up your example and remove the extraneous bits. That way, we can easily discern your problem and help you faster.

Comment: This example is not valid Java code plus there is one extra `}` - is it some content of a textfile that you have to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`invoiceList[INDEX].PROPERTYNAME`. For an example: `invoiceList[0].ismanual` will return true. Basically you need to iterate with a for loop through the list and have a global variable in which you can store the sums.

```
Decimal total = 0;
for(Integer i = 0; i < invoiceList.length(); i++)
{    total += invoiceList[i].netamount; 
}
```